# Getting named arguments from a string query

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I get arguments from a string that has a `letter:answer` format with spaces, like this
`q:Best President d:Obama 1:2012`

and transform it into either

```js
{
  "q": "Best President",
  "d": "Obama",
  "1": "2012"
}
```

or

`["q:Best President", "d:Obama", "1:2012"]`

Function or regex is fine, thanks in advance

Comment: That format isn't reliably parsable. Can the values contain `:` characters?

Comment: Is it always a single character before `:`?

Comment: @Karizma `1` isn't exactly an _"alphabet character"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split on spaces with a positive lookead matching `[a-zA-Z0-9]:`. From there, you can map the array to an object using another split

For example

```js
const str = 'q:Best President d:Obama 1:2012'

const arr = str.split(/ (?=[a-zA-Z0-9]:)/)
console.log('arr', arr)

const obj = arr.map(v => v.split(':')).reduce((o, [k, v]) => ({
  ...o,
  [k]: v
}), Object.create(null))
console.log('obj', obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of array you can just:

```
let entries = ["q:Best President", "d:Obama", "1:2012"].map(item => item.split(':'))
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(entries)
```

Easy and fun way :)

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the problem, thought that string OR array TO obj :(

Comment: It's cool, thanks for the attempt though, forgot `Object.fromEntries` existed

Comment: Me too. Nicer than my reduce operation